# Devise : No route matches {:controller=>"devise/about"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Recently I added the gem 'devise' to my application. I then went through the basic install steps as documented on the devise github page. After doing the install of devise, I ran the command:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Then I ran the command:

```
 rails generate devise User
```

Both of these commands were successful.

I then ensured that I have a defined **root_url** in my config; in my case it's:

```
root :to => "sample#index"
```

After doing this, I ran the command:

```
 rails g devise:views
```

This also worked perfectly, according to the command line responses.

After performing all of these steps, I ran rake routes, to ensure that the new devise routes and paths were available. I then restarted my application server.

The problem that I'm running into is when I try to go to **localhost:3000/users/sign_up** I get the error message: **No route matches {:controller=>"devise/about"}**

I can clearly see the route when I rake it:

```
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new
```

Because I can see the route, I am unsure as to what the problem is and/or where the problem exists at. Has anyone else seen this issue before?

As an aside, I'm currently running Ruby-2.0.0-p195, and Rails 3.2.13

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how your routes file looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your log files (`log/development.log`) for more information on the error - you are most likely coding a link on that page with an invalid route.

Note that the error is about `devise/about`, not the `users/sign_up` that you're visiting.

Comment: Please see my note below! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You put me on the right path. I checked the logs and I found that a link that I was using in my **Application.html.erb** layout file was setup to:

```
 <%= link_to( :controller => 'about' ... etc. ) %>
```

To fix this, I changed the path to:

```
 <%= link_to(  :controller => '/about' ... etc. ) %>
```

By adding the forward slash, Rails was properly able to find the location of my controller and this error went away.

Thanks.